# Change default Springboot Rest Data default links

Tags: spring, nginx

```
{ "_links" : {
    "orders" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/orders"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/alps"
    }
  }
}
```

This result is generated by Springboot Rest Data.  I plan to put this application behind Nginx that will listen to secured port (443).  How do I change _links port from 8080 to 443 even though my application still runs on 8080?

Answer (score 0):

spring boot data rest will read host and scheme from request as base url,so you should tell spring boot the real host and scheme.
this nginx config work for me:

```
location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-forwarded-Prefix /api;
}
```